# Is there a way to include source positions in the rendered output of a Twirl template?

Tags: twirl

The *.scala files that are generated by Twirl include the information that binds the generated code to the lines in source templates. Is there an option to further include this information in the output of template's render function?

If there isn't such an option what could be the recommended way of implementing this feature? Right know I cannot find where the debugging information from generated *.scala template files is consumed...